# LAG function to return previous rows by discarding null values

Tags: sql, hive, presto, trino

I am trying to find the previous pages visited by a person from web table. I am using lag function to find previous pages that the person has visited only if there was a next page visited.

web table:

| id | visit_time | webpage_visited |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2024-03-14 10:00:01 | google.com |
| 1 | 2024-03-14 10:00:07 |  |
| 1 | 2024-03-14 10:01:15 |  |
| 1 | 2024-03-14 10:01:10 | espn.com |
| 1 | 2024-03-14 10:02:01 |  |

When I use below SQL, the values returned are not considering the null/blank values between the rows.

**SQL used:**

```
select id, 
visit_time, 
webpage_visited, 
coalesce(lag(webpage_visited, 1) over (partition by id order by visit_time  asc), 'none') as previous_webpage_visited
from web
```

Please advice how I can achieve the below expected output.

**Expected output:**

| id | visit_time | webpage_visited | previous_webpage_visited |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2024-03-14 10:00:01 | google.com | None |
| 1 | 2024-03-14 10:00:07 |  |  |
| 1 | 2024-03-14 10:01:15 |  |  |
| 1 | 2024-03-14 10:01:10 | espn.com | google.com |
| 1 | 2024-03-14 10:02:01 |  |  |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick consists of two parts - use [`IGNORE NULLS` for your window function](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/window.html#value-functions) and apply the window function only if the current value is not null:

```sql
sample data
WITH dataset(id, visit_time, webpage_visited) AS (
   values (1,'2024-03-14 10:00:01','google.com'),
        (1,'2024-03-14 10:00:07',NULL),
        (1,'2024-03-14 10:01:15',NULL),
        (1,'2024-03-14 10:01:10','espn.com'),
        (1,'2024-03-14 10:02:01',NULL)
)

-- query
select id,
       visit_time,
       webpage_visited,
       if(webpage_visited is not null,
           coalesce(lag(webpage_visited, 1) IGNORE NULLS over(partition by id order by visit_time), 'none'))
           as previous_webpage_visited
from dataset
order by visit_time;
```

Output:

| id | visit_time | webpage_visited | previous_webpage_visited |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2024-03-14 10:00:01 | google.com | none |
| 1 | 2024-03-14 10:00:07 | NULL | NULL |
| 1 | 2024-03-14 10:01:10 | espn.com | google.com |
| 1 | 2024-03-14 10:01:15 | NULL | NULL |
| 1 | 2024-03-14 10:02:01 | NULL | NULL |

**UPD**

To handle empty/whitespace entries you can preprocess them, for example with subquery:

```sql
select id,
       visit_time,
       webpage_visited,
       if(webpage_visited_sanitized is not null,
           coalesce(lag(webpage_visited_sanitized, 1) IGNORE NULLS over(partition by id order by visit_time), 'none'))
           as previous_webpage_visited
from (select *,
             if(trim(webpage_visited) = '', null, webpage_visited) webpage_visited_sanitized
      from dataset
     );
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I just tried the same in Athena, the query doesn't seem to return results as above.

Comment: @vvazza You have tried exactly the query from the answer?

Comment: Yes, both the query that I posted and the one you replied are returning the same result in Athena :/ I have multiple NULL records next to the first page visited before visiting the next page.

Comment: @vvazza 1) have you tried the full query including the sample data? 2) _"I have multiple NULL records next to the first page visited before visiting the next page."_ - can you please elaborate, TBH I don't understand?

Comment: @vvazza also is there a chance that you have empty strings instead of nulls in some rows?

Comment: I tried with TRIM(webpage_visited)<>'' as well, same results

Comment: @vvazza if you have empty/whitespace strings then ignore nulls will not work as is.

Comment: Looks like they are empty strings. How can i handle this?

Comment: @vvazza please see the update. basically you need to sanitize such entries, for example with subquery (or you can perform the calculation twice in the `lag` and in the condition)

Comment: Sorry, thought I did already. Looks like I didn’t. Just upvoted :)